# Best way to populate a javascript typed array?

Tags: javascript, literals, typed-arrays

What is the best way to populate a javascript typed array with literal data?

Recently I've been working a lot with javascript typed arrays for some mathematical work.  In particular, I'm using lots of Float32Array objects.

I often have to manually populate their values.  With a regular array, there is the following literal syntax available: `var a = [0,1,2];` But there seems to be no equivalent way to populate a typed array, so I find I have to do it with lots of individual statements;

```
var a = new Float32Array(3);
a[0] = 0;
a[1] = 1;
a[2] = 2;
```

This gets very annoying if there's more than about 4 values.  And it seems wasteful too, both in terms of script size, and javascript execution, because it has to interpret all those individual statements.

Another approach I've used is creating a setter function:

```
var populateArray(a,vals) {
    var N = vals.length;
    for (var i=0; i<N; i++) {a[i]=vals[i];}
};
var a = new Float32Array(3);
populateArray(a,[0,1,2]);
```

But this seems quite wasteful too.  I have to create a regular array as big as the typed array first, to feed into the populateArray function, and then there's the iteration.

So... the question is: Is there a more direct and efficient way to fill a typed array with literal data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not simply do `new Float32Array([1,2,3]);`

Look at the [constructor overloads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Float32Array):

> Float32Array Float32Array(
>     unsigned long length
>   );
>
> Float32Array Float32Array(
>     TypedArray array
>   );
>
> Float32Array Float32Array(
>     sequence array
>   );
>
> Float32Array Float32Array(
>     ArrayBuffer buffer,
>     optional unsigned long byteOffset,
>     optional unsigned long length
>   );

Comment: or, if the array is already declared, can also use a.set([1,2,3])

Comment: Wow - I didn't know you could do that!  Unbelievably simple.  I can't believe I haven't seen that before.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @DanielHoward Np. Sometimes it's easier than you think ;)